# Express-validator does not return object in async validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation

I am validating a login form with express-validator and passport.js, using a local strategy:

```
login: function() {
  passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
    function(req, username, password, done) {
      req.check('username', 'Incorrect user and/or password.').doesUserExists(password);
      req.check('password', 'Password cannot be empty.').notEmpty();

      req.asyncValidationErrors(true)
      .then(function(user) {
        return done(null, user);
      })
      .catch(function(errors) {
        if (errors) return done(null, false, req.flash('error', errors));
      });
    }
  ));
}
```

The function `doesUserExists()` is a custom asynchronous validation, which query for the user, compare the password provided with the hashed password in the database, and resolves it:

```
doesUserExists: function(username, password) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    User.findOne({ username: username })
    .then(function(user) {
      if (user) return user;
      if (!user) reject(user);
    })
    .then(function(user) {
      user.comparePassword(password, function(error, isMatch) {
        if (isMatch) return user;
        else reject(user);
      });
      resolve(user);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      if (error) reject(error);
    });
  });
}
```

So far it is working perfectly, except when the user and the password are matched, and the promise is resolved, no object (user) is returned to the `req.asyncValidationErrors()` function, preventing its `.then()` block to  redirect to the user profile.

I must add that I'm pretty new to promises, and not sure if what I'm expecting should happen. Perhaps some misunderstanding about how it works is leading me to think erroneous.

### Update

For now, I decided to make another database query for the validated user/password:

```
req.asyncValidationErrors(true)
  .then(function() {
    User.findOne({ username: username })
    .then(function(user) {
      return done(null, user);
    });
  })
  .catch(function(errors) {
    if (errors) {
      return done(null, false, req.flash('error', errors));
    }
  });
```

Extra database queries are not elegant, but...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create new Promise if you can just return the Promise returned by User.find :

```
doesUserExists: function(username, password) {
    return User.findOne({ username: username })
    .then(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        // Also here is a mistake because we can't return inside 
        // the comparePassword callback, and that's why user is not get back
        user.comparePassword(password, function(error, isMatch) {
          if (isMatch) return user;
          else throw new Error('my error');
        });
      }
      else throw new Error('my error');
    });
}
// Now use it as follows
req
.check('username', 'Incorrect user and/or password.')
.doesUserExists(username, password)
.then(function(user){/* user authenticated */})
.catch(function(error){/* user not atuhenticated */});
```

So I guess you can compare password later and problem solved :

```
doesUserExists: function(username, password) {
    return User.findOne({ username: username })
    .then(function(user) {
      if (user) return user;
      else throw new Error('my error');
    });
}
// Now use it as follows
req
.check('username', 'Incorrect user and/or password.')
.doesUserExists(username, password)
.then(function(user){
  /* From here, user was found */
  user.comparePassword(password, function(error, isMatch) {
    if (isMatch){ /* Do whatever with the user authenticated */ }
    else { /* Do whatever you want when password don't match */ }
  });
})
.catch(function(error){/* user not found */});
```

If you're doing more than one async validation, I suggest you to use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to make to execute parallel async functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't know that Mongoose queries were promises; this could be useful later. I tried your implementation, but for some reason, `express-validator` throws an error `req.check().then() is not a function`. Thanks for the tip about `Promises.all()`, I was thinking about it but wasn't sure whether to use it or not.